# Cannot create a globally named event in low integrity process

Tags: windows, security, synchronization

I have a code which works fine:

```
HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, L"Global\\MyEvent");
```

But when I run it from the low integrity process, the hEvent is 0 and `GetLastError()` returns **ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED**.

How can I create an event in this case?

Comment: Is the low integrity process creating the event, or opening the event which was created by a higher integrity process?

Comment: Yes, low integrity process is trying to create the event. Is this possible?